# Plot getting bolder after each iteration

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, I am generating plots on the same figure over a given iteration. As I have multiple plots there, I want them to start faded and as the iteration goes further, they get bolder and bolder. It is important to have plots with the same color.

A made up code in case you have any want to try yourself:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

i = np.array([1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0])
x = np.arange(-10, 10, .1)

for i in range(0,len(i)):
    rv1 = norm(loc = 0., scale = 1.0*i)
    plt.plot(x,rv1.pdf(x),  color ='b')

plt.show()
```

I want my plot to resemble something like this:

[image]

Comment: To make them bolder, use `linewidth=i+1`, to make them fade in color, use `alpha=(i+1)/len(array)`. (Don't call two different things `i`!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using the `alpha` argument to `plot`, e.g.:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

idx = np.array([1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0])
xxx = np.arange(-10, 10, .1)

for i in range(0,len(idx)):
    rv1 = norm(loc = 0., scale = 1.0*i)
    plt.plot(xxx,rv1.pdf(xxx),  color ='b', alpha=i / len(idx))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that I renamed some variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable line width and the transparency parameter, `alpha` as following. Start with some initial values and then increase the line thickness by 20% (for example) and decrease the alpha by 10%

P.S: I read the comment of IOBE and added it to my for loop for readers. Don't call the iterator variable and the array by the same name `i`. I have now used `ii` in the for loop

```
wid = 0.8
alpha=0.9

for ii in range(0,len(i)):
    rv1 = norm(loc = 0., scale = 1.0*ii)
    plt.plot(x,rv1.pdf(x),  color ='b', lw=wid, alpha=alpha)
    wid *= 1.2
    alpha *= 0.9
```

[image]